# Can you change the position of the mouse pointer in unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine

For context, I want to make a game where there is a AI player that can fight you, and you play as the mouse pointer, (Kind of like animator VS animation). I have a trigger collider enabled when the AI attacks and I am wondering if I can make the mouse have a knockback from this attack.

sorry if this was confusing, I have never seen anything like this before and was wondering how I could pull it off.

Comment: Yes you can usually, there are some situations when not..

Comment: You can move the actual mouse position using, see [Unity Cursor Warping](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.inputsystem@1.0/manual/Mouse.html#:~:text=To%20move%20the%20cursor%20to,screen%20coordinates%2C%20just%20like%20Mouse.). However, this might not be desired behavior you want but go ahead and try it out I guess. Maybe disable mouse input when applying the „knockback“. Play around, see if it achieves what you want. If not, think of other ways:)